# Why is a SDL Tridion 2011 Custom Resolver called twice when publishing a Component?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have a Custom Resolver which is applied to items of the type *Publication*, *StructureGroup*, *Page* and *Component*.  The code runs as expected, but I am not clear on exactly when the code is called.
My *Tridion.ContentManager.config* file contains the following extract:

```
<resolving>
    <mappings>
        <clear/>
        <add itemType="Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page">
            <resolvers>
                <add type="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.PageResolver" assembly="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=360aac4d3354074b"/>
                <add type="UrbanCherry.Net.SDLTridion.CustomResolvers.DynamicBinaryLinkResolver" assembly="UrbanCherry.Net.SDLTridion.CustomResolvers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e7729a00ff9574fb"/>
            </resolvers>
        </add>
        <add itemType="Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.PageTemplate">
            <resolvers>
                <add type="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.PageTemplateResolver" assembly="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=360aac4d3354074b"/>
            </resolvers>
        </add>
        <add itemType="Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component">
            <resolvers>
                <add type="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ComponentResolver" assembly="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=360aac4d3354074b"/>
                <add type="UrbanCherry.Net.SDLTridion.CustomResolvers.DynamicBinaryLinkResolver" assembly="UrbanCherry.Net.SDLTridion.CustomResolvers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e7729a00ff9574fb"/>
            </resolvers>
        </add>
        <add itemType="Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.ComponentTemplate">
            <resolvers>
                <add type="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ComponentTemplateResolver" assembly="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=360aac4d3354074b"/>
            </resolvers>
        </add>
        <add itemType="Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Publication">
            <resolvers>
                <add type="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.PublicationResolver" assembly="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=360aac4d3354074b"/>
                <add type="UrbanCherry.Net.SDLTridion.CustomResolvers.DynamicBinaryLinkResolver" assembly="UrbanCherry.Net.SDLTridion.CustomResolvers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e7729a00ff9574fb"/>
            </resolvers>
        </add>
        <add itemType="Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.StructureGroup">
            <resolvers>
                <add type="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.StructureGroupResolver" assembly="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=360aac4d3354074b"/>
                <add type="UrbanCherry.Net.SDLTridion.CustomResolvers.DynamicBinaryLinkResolver" assembly="UrbanCherry.Net.SDLTridion.CustomResolvers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e7729a00ff9574fb"/>
            </resolvers>
        </add>
        <add itemType="Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Category">
            <resolvers>
                <add type="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.CategoryResolver" assembly="Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=360aac4d3354074b"/>
            </resolvers>
        </add> 
    </mappings>
</resolving>
```

When I publish a *Publication*, *StructureGroup* or *Page* my Custom Resolver gets called once (which is what I had expected), however when I publish a *Component*  (the *Schema* of which is linked to one *Component Template* which produces a *Dynamic Component Presentation*) the Custom Resolver is called twice.

Is this expected behavior? If not, can anyone suggest why my Resolver is called a second time?

Comment: interesting one, the component doesn't happen to be on a page as well does it?

Comment: Nope, not on a page. I tried removing the resolver from all item types except for Component thinking along the same lines, but it still happened. I am wondering if it calls it once for the Component and once for each CT associated with the Components Schema. I am going to make a new CT now and see if it gets called 3 times.

Comment: yeah that's what jumps to mind for me as well, let me know the results  of your test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Resolver is called once for the Component, and once for each Component Template associated with the Component's Schema. Adding an additional CT for that Schema increased the number of calls to three.

It is not clear if this is a bug or by design, but explains the number of calls. Interesting the Custom Resolver is only called once when Un-Publishing the Component

Comment: It's nice when you answer your own question :) I would have said that it's called once for the Component itself (thus to maybe resolve to the pages that include that Component) and once for the CTs. But I did not check this information before, nor do I if it's by design...

Answer (score 1):

I have observed that a custom resolver is invoked for each publication target which is "in scope" for the current publish action.